# relativelayout wrap_content not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-wrap-content

this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tt">



<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/trashParent"
 android:visibility="visible"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/bgtrash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/parentTrash"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    < 
</LinearLayout>
```

as we can see the parent View with id `android:id="@+id/tt"`

its height and width its wrap_content i know if some child have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` so the wrap_conent not work its will be like match_parent

but now i do this in java i have to method will hide and show the child

```
private void hide(){
    trashParent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    parentTrash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} 

private void show(){
    trashParent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    parentTrash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

now when i hide the child and make it wrap_content its still match parent this the run code

```
  hide();
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams chatHeadParentParamst = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


   tt.setLayoutParams(chatHeadParentParamst);
   tt.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

change tt height to wrap_content because its be match parent some time 
        but after change to wrap_conent is still like match_parent
        i think the child still not `Gone` and i set it to wrap_conent

because when i use delay its work this the delay

```
hide();

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide(); // i dont no must i call it again to work

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams chatHeadParentParamst = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            tt.setLayoutParams(chatHeadParentParamst);
            tt.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

            Log.d("called now delay","wwwwwwwww");

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1100);
```

with delay now its size chnage to wrap_conent  without delay it be same like match_parent but all child visibility was `gone` any solotio without delay i cant use LinerLayout i must use RaltiveLayout becuase i need child one over one

Comment: instead of `gone` try with `INVISIBLE`

Comment: @rookieDeveloper `INVISIBLE` will hide only and space will still

Comment: Have you tried to change layout_width="match_parent" of the first linear layout (that one with -> android:background="@drawable/bgtrash") to -> layout_width="100dp"

Comment: @Tony problem in height not in width :/